# Connect to remote database with ip address in workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to a remote databases using an ip address ,login and password,the instance name is SQLEXPRESS ,Any idea how can i connect to this databases with workbench ?

Comment: Just put in the credentials in the form. Usually port 3306 if that's not set by default

Comment: Connecting to MySQL server ...
Can't connect to MySQL server x.x.x.x(10060)

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to a MySQL instance? If the instance name is SQLEXPRESS, I wonder if it's actually Microsoft SQL Server Express. You won't be able to use MySQL Workbench for that. Instead, use [SQL Server Management Studio Express](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the localhost server (or IP) with the correct IP.

You might need to create a dedicated user for external connection, since default **root** user is restricted to connect only from localhost.